You have requested a non-existent parameter "container.build_hash"
While activating the Limit login attempts feature in my Symfony 7.1 project, following the official docs

installed the component (v7.1.1) via composer (composer require symfony/rate-limiter)
edited the security.yaml to allow limiting login attempts:

        # config/packages/security.yaml
        security:
            firewalls:
                main:
                    login_throttling: null

Everything worked fine before, but now, when opening my project or checking the output of symfony console debug:config security, I get this exception:

You have requested a non-existent parameter "container.build_hash"

I haven't modified the service container parameters.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/57300

This was supposedly fixed on 7.1.1. (See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/57263). Latest patch version for Symfony is 7.1.4. Have you checked that you're running the latest version of everything?

Please try updating the SecurityBundle through composer update symfony/security-bundle

This was a known bug in first 7.1 Symfony release.
See the bug report:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/57257
It was fixed in 7.1.1:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/57263
So you should only need to update to the latest version (7.1.4 at time of writing) to get rid of this error.

Yep, that's what I did. Just checked, I use Symfony 7.1.4 now and everything is fine. Thanks!
